# Merging multiple ggplots due to dataframe size

Tags: r, ggplot2, bigdata

I have some big data, this is a much smaller example:

```
demo1 <- data.frame(
  df1 <- rnorm(100000000, mean = 6),
  df2 <- rnorm(100000000, mean = 12),
  df3 <- rnorm(100000000, mean = 18)
)
```

For each of these variables I would like a density plot.

It takes quite some time to create a visualise each plot.

I want to create each plot then bring them all together.

I cannot use a factor to do this (like in the below example) as my local machine cannot handle the size of the total dataset.

The final result would look like this:

[image: example plot]

Image from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-density-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Comment: Sample 1M points (or even 100k points) from each and build a density based on that. Using 100M (or more) points for a density plot seems pointless.

Comment: Agree - but perhaps 100M+ points is "point"full?

Comment: I would really rather not subsample at all. The data are absolutely not normal, I have thought about ordering and plotting but I would also like a solution where I don't have to compromise

Comment: We often get into this mindset of wanting to use **all the data** even when it's not needed. Take a single one of your data sets and sample 100k points, 1M points, 10M points, the full thing and make density plots with each. I'd be willing to bet you can hardly tell them apart. And even if you can pick out the 100k point version, you can still go up without giving your computer headaches.

Comment: The issue is `ggplot` stores the data as part of the plot object. If you run `g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_density()`, you can access the data with `g$data`. So you're copying your massive data with every plot - and if your machine can't handle all the datasets together, it can't handle all the plots together. And ggplot's internals depend on having access to that object, at least to some extent.

Comment: If you want to make it work, you can use `stats::density` to calculate the density and save out a summary data frame with just the density values enough x-values to have a nice high-res plot (1000 values is plenty. 3k is extreme - saving more x values than pixels you will view the plot at is pointless). Then you'd have 3 small data sets you can easily combine and plot with `ggplot`. But really, if you're going to be working with really big data I'd strongly suggest relying on sampling whenever practical, you'll be able to work **much** faster.

Comment: Thanks for the time taken to explain, I have done exactly as you said and its spot on!